# Implementation function inside OnClickListener - Android

Tags: java, android

i wanna call this method "CriarNotificacao" -> CreateNotification, inside my function OnClick, but get an error that i can't implement it, My friend tell me to create a anonymous class, i don't understand "too much".. How can i do it? Is there a simple method for this?

```
package br.com.notification;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CreateNotificationActivity extends Activity
{

    Button btnNotifica;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("Notificação disparada.");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Texto que aparecerá na barra de status (chamada para a notificação)
        String tickerText = "Você recebeu uma mensagem.";

        // Detalhes da notificação
        CharSequence titulo = "André";
        CharSequence mensagem = "Exemplo de notificação";

        // Exibe a notificação
        //criarNotificacao(this, tickerText, titulo, mensagem, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);

        //Começar a Brincar AQUI!
        btnNotifica = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btnNotifica.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //CALL NOTIFICATION HERE
            }         

        });


    }



    // Exibe a notificacao
    public void criarNotificacao(Context context, CharSequence mensagemBarraStatus,
        CharSequence titulo, CharSequence mensagem, Class activity) {
        // Recupera o serviço do NotificationManager
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.jo, mensagemBarraStatus, System.currentTimeMillis());

        // PendingIntent para executar a Activity se o usuário selecionar a notificação
        PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, activity), 0);

        // Flag utilizada para remover a notificação da barra de status
        // quando o usuário clicar nela
        n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Informações
        n.setLatestEventInfo(this, titulo, mensagem, p);

        // Espera 100ms e vibra por 250ms, espera por mais 100ms e vibra por 500ms
        n.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500 };

        //Id da Notificacao
        nm.notify(R.string.app_name, n);
    }

}
```

Comment: As you implement Button.OnClickListener - that's the anonymous class implementation. But what is the error that you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine the error you're getting is because you're trying to call `this` within the scope of `onClick`, which won't result in the current `Context`.

What you need to do is instantiate a final variable outside of the click listener to store the current Context.

Also, all other variables that are non-global, will need to be instantiated as final as well; in order to be used within the onClick handler.

```
// Texto que aparecerá na barra de status (chamada para a notificação)
final String tickerText = "Você recebeu uma mensagem.";

// Detalhes da notificação
final CharSequence titulo = "André";
final CharSequence mensagem = "Exemplo de notificação";

// Current Context
final Context context = this;

//Começar a Brincar AQUI!
btnNotifica = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

btnNotifica.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        criarNotificacao(context, tickerText, titulo, mensagem, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
    }
});
```

Comment: The "context" get error "Cannot find symbol, symbol: variable context" what is it?

Comment: Try as @ABFORCE said; replacing `context` with `CreateNotificationActivity.this` as that will also work.